# Plotly : Difference between mode and add_trace

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, r-plotly

```
dat = c(1:100)

fig1 = plot_ly(x = ~x)

fig2 = fig1%>%add_trace(y=~rnorm(100), mode= "lines")
```

The outputs for "fig1" and "fig2" are: [image: fig1] and [image: fig2] respectively.

I could also get "fig2" using the following code:

```
fig3 = plot_ly(x= ~dat, y = ~rnorm(100))%>%add_lines()
```

Can someone explain what's the difference individual traces like (add_histogram, add_lines etc..) and the function add_trace with an appropriate mode?

Answer (score 1):

`add_histogram`, `add_lines` etc. are convenience functions with a preset trace type (internally they are setting the according type and call `add_trace_classed` - type e.g. `add_lines` in the console to inspect the function).

`add_trace` is a general function to **creates traces of any available type**.

Your third option to create traces is via the `plot_ly()` function itself.

Please see the example section of `?add_trace` for additinal information:

> the `plot_ly()` function initiates an object, and if no trace type
> is specified, it sets a sensible default p <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~uempmed) p
>
> some `add_*()` functions are a specific case of a trace type
> for example, `add_markers()` is a scatter trace with mode of markers add_markers(p)

If you don't specify a trace type in `plot_ly` it is set based on the data you provided:

```
library(plotly)

dat = data.frame(x = 1:100)

fig1 = plot_ly(data = dat, x = ~x)
# No trace type specified:
#   Based on info supplied, a 'histogram' trace seems appropriate.
# Read more about this trace type -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#histogram

fig1a = plot_ly(data = dat, x = ~x, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")

fig2 = fig1 %>% add_trace(y=~rnorm(100), mode = "lines")
```